# Hartshorne Chapter IV Exercise 5.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

If $X$ is a curve of genus $ \geq 2$ over a field of characteristic $0$, show that the group $\operatorname{Aut} X$ of automorphisms of $X$ is finite.

Hint: If $X$ is hyperelliptic, use the unique $g_1^2$ and show that $\operatorname{Aut} X$ permutes the ramification points of the $2$-fold covering $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$. If $X$ is not hyperelliptic, show that $\operatorname{Aut} X$ permutes the hyperosculation points of the canonical embedding.

I have a proof in the case that $X$ is hyperelliptic, but as I am not very familiar with hyperosculation points, I am struggling to prove the non-hyperelliptic case.

Could anyone give me a hint regarding that?

Comment: Have you done the exercise from section IV.2 about hyperosculation points? I believe the idea here is just that any automorphism permutes these (they are essentially generalizations of the ramification points in the hyperelliptic case), and since there are only finitely many of them the automorphism group sits inside the symmetric group on the hyperosculation points.

Comment: But why do they get permuted?

Comment: An automorphism of $X$ induces an automorphism of $|K|$ and hence embedding $X$ in to projective space by $|K|$ (prop IV.5.2), an automorphism of the pair $X\hookrightarrow \Bbb P^n$. This preserves the hyperosculation points, since the count of $P$ in $H\cap X$ is the same as the count of $P'$ in $H'\cap X'$ where an automorphism takes $P\to P'$ and $H\to H'$, so there's a map from $Aut(X)$ to the symmetric group on the hyperosculation points. The only thing I'm missing is why this has to be injective - perhaps @TabesBridges could explain?

Comment: @KReiser Sure. It suffices of course to show that the kernel of $\operatorname{Aut}(X) \to S_N$ is trivial, i.e. that any automorphism fixing the hyperosculation points is actually the identity. This follows from a few facts: (1) any automorphism of $\mathbb P^n$ fixing $n+1$ points is the identity, (2) canonical curves are projectively normal, and (3) counting the number of hyperosculation points as a function of $g$, which should be greater than $g$ (the target dimension of the canonical embedding $+1$) for $g \ge 3$.

Comment: @TabesBridges thanks for the details! For (1), I'm pretty sure it's $n+2$ points in linearly general position. For (2), I'm not sure what projective normality gets you or why - is it the appropriate general position condition which makes (1) work? For (3), by the formula in exercise IV.4.6(b), it ought to be $g(g^2-1)$ (unless I've made an error) which does exactly what you want. Now I suppose one of us should write this all up as an answer...

Answer (score 3):

When $X$ is not hyperelliptic, $|K|$ is very ample and therefore embeds $X$ in to $\Bbb P^{g-1}$ as a curve of degree $2g-2$. The hyperosculation points of this embedding are exactly the points $P\in X$ with a global section $s\in\Omega_X(X)$ so that $s$ vanishes to order at least $g$ at $P$. Since $\Omega_X$ is preserved by any automorphism, we see that this condition is preserved by automorphisms and so $\operatorname{Aut} X$ acts on the set of hyperosculation points. Since there are $n(n+1)(g-1)+(n+1)d=g^3-g$ hyperosculation points in characteristic zero by exercise IV.4.6, all we need to do is to show the kernel of this map is finite in order to show $\operatorname{Aut} X$ is finite. In fact, we'll show that the kernel is trivial by showing that automorphism of a genus $g$ curve fixing more than $2g+2$ points is trivial. This proves the claim because $g^3-g>2g+2$ for $g>2$ (all curves of genus 2 are hyperelliptic anyways, so the only time we'd use the hyperosculation points is when $g>2$).

To show that a nontrivial automorphism $\sigma$ of a curve $X$ of genus $g$ has at most $2g+2$ fixed points, I claim that given a nontrivial automorphism $\sigma$, we can always find a nonconstant rational function $f\in K(X)$ with at most $g+1$ poles (counted with multiplicity) so that $f-\sigma f$ is not constant. Then $f-\sigma f$ has zeroes at every fixed point of $\sigma$, and $f-\sigma f$ has at most $2g+2$ poles because each of $f$ and $\sigma f$ have at most $g+1$ poles. As the number of poles and zeroes of any nonconstant rational function on a curve are equal (they're both equal to the degree of the map to $\Bbb P^1$ given by $f$), this proves that $\sigma$ has at most $2g+2$ fixed points.

First, for any effective divisor of degree $g+1$, we can find a nonconstant function with poles contained in $D$: by Riemann-Roch, $l(D)-l(K-D)=g+1-g+1=2$, so $l(D)\geq 2$, and therefore $l(D)$ contains a nonconstant rational function. Next, we can always find a degree $g+1$ effective divisor which isn't fixed by $\sigma$: just pick some point $x\in X$ not fixed by $\sigma$ (which we can always find because $\sigma$ is not the identity) and look at $(g+1)x$. So $(f-\sigma f)_\infty$ is of degree at most $2g+2$ and therefore $(f-\sigma f)_0$ is of degree at most $2g+2$ and therefore can contain at most $2g+2$ points, and we've won.

Answer (score 0):

Embed $X$ into $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ by its canonical linear system, then $X$ is a nondegenerate curve of degree $2g-2$, and assume it has been known that every automorphism of $X$ permutes its hyperosculation locus (see the answer of [KReiser](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4375867)).

The following obvious lemma will be useful:

**Lemma:** Let $n\ge 1$, and $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$ consists of finite closed points and is not contained in any hyperplane, then
$$G_S=\{\alpha\in\mathrm{Aut}(X):\alpha(S)=S\},$$
is a finite group.

---

Since the embedding is canonical, each automorphism $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ can be extended to an automorphism $\overline{\sigma}\in\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$, and since $X$ is nondegenerate, such extension is unique. So we have an injective homomorphism
$$\phi\colon\mathrm{Aut}(X)\to\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^{g-1}).$$
Denote by $S$ for the hyperosculation locus of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$, then we know that $S$ is a finite set consists of $g^3-g$ closed points in $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ by exercise IV.4.6 in Hartshorne's book. Since $g\ge 2$, we then have $g^3-g>2g$, but the degree of $X$ is $2g-2$, so $S$ cannot be contained in any hyperplane. Since $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ permutes hyperosculation points, its extension $\overline{\sigma}$ satisfies $\overline{\sigma}(S)=S$. So by our lemma, the image of homomorphism $\phi$ is contained in a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})$. Thus $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is finite as desired.